# PyInstaller exe freezing but .py script works as expected

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So I have a script to combine a set of .txt files and it utilises threading to reduce the processing time. I now need to package the script to an exe for other users who do not use python to be able to utilise the tool.

When running the .py file, I have no issues with generating the GUI and running the script; however, when packaging it with PyInstaller, the GUI freezes at line 45 (highlighted with comment below). I suspected the threading could be creating an issue, so I added a print statement to the for loop that generates the threads, but this print statement is never reached with the .exe. So I'm stumped as to what could be causing this and how I can solve this.

I am creating the exe with:

```
pyinstaller --onefile binFileCombine.py
```

but have also tried installing all the packages individually with --hidden-import, to no avail.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
import gzip as gz
import threading
import queue

def worker(q, df_list, files):
    while not q.empty():
        file = q.get()
        if file.endswith('.bin.txt'):
            print('Reading file: ' + file)
            temp_df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter='\t', header=0, engine='python')
            date = temp_df.columns[0] 
            temp_df[date] = temp_df[date].apply(lambda x: date + ' ' + x)
            #Delete the last column:
            temp_df = temp_df.iloc[:, :-1]
            temp_df.columns = ['Timestamp', 'Wind speed', 'Own consumption']
            df_list.append(temp_df)
            update_progress_bar(len(df_list), len(files))
        q.task_done()

def combineBinFilesThreaded():
    folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if not folder_selected:
        return
    
    print(folder_selected)
    
    os.chdir(folder_selected)
    files = os.listdir(folder_selected)
    run_button.configure(state='disabled', text='Please wait')    
    
    df_list = []
    q = queue.Queue()

    progressBarLabel.configure(text='Reading & combining files...')
```

Freezes after the above line, and the print at the start of the below for never executes (only for .exe)

```
    # Create 4 worker threads
    for i in range(4):
        print('Starting thread: ' + str(i))
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(q, df_list, files))
        t.start()
    
    # Put the files in the queue
    for file in files:
        q.put(file)
    
    # Wait for all the tasks in the queue to be processed
    q.join()
    print('Done joining')
    # Combine all the dataframes
    df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    print('Done concatenating')
    chunksize = 500000
    #Add if statement to check if combinedBinFile exists so that it doesn't append to itself
    if os.path.exists('combinedBinFile.csv'):
        os.remove('combinedBinFile.csv')
    
    update_progress_bar(0, len(df))
    progressBarLabel.configure(text='Writing combined file...')
    #Write the headers to the file first:
    df.iloc[:0].to_csv('combinedBinFile.csv', index=False)
    
    for i in range(0, len(df), chunksize):
        print('Writing chunk: ' + str(i))
        df.iloc[i:i+chunksize].to_csv('combinedBinFile.csv', index=False, header=False, mode='a')
        update_progress_bar(i+chunksize, len(df))
            
    print('Done writing')
    run_button.configure(state='normal', text='Select folder')
    progressBarLabel.configure(text='Done: File saved as combinedBinFile.csv')
    
    
def update_progress_bar(current_value, total_value):
    progress_bar['value'] = current_value
    progress_bar['maximum'] = total_value
    root.update_idletasks()

def run_script():
    threading.Thread(target=combineBinFilesThreaded, daemon=True).start()
    
    

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-topmost', True)
root.configure(background='lightgray')
root.title('Bin File Combiner')
root.geometry('400x200')

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('alt')
style.configure('cyan.Horizontal.TProgressbar', troughcolor='lightgray', background='darkcyan')
style.configure('TButton', font=('Calibri', 10))
style.configure('TLabel', font=('Calibri', 10))
    
run_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Select folder', command=run_script, takefocus=False)
run_button.pack(pady=20)

progressBarLabel = ttk.Label(root, text='Waiting for user input...', background='lightgray')
progressBarLabel.pack(pady=0)

progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal', length=200, mode='determinate', style='cyan.Horizontal.TProgressbar')
progress_bar.pack(pady = 5)

def on_closing():
    root.destroy()
    
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_closing)

root.mainloop()
```

Any tips to debugging/fixing this are much appreciated. Also this is the entire code so should run, except for the specific formatting I have for my .txt files: I can't provide the files, but the general format is:

```
11_07_2023    Wind    Power 
16 30 00 006    6,48    0   
16 30 00 016    6,48    0   
16 30 00 026    6,48    0   
16 30 00 036    6,48    0   
16 30 00 046    6,48    0   
16 30 00 056    6,48    0   
16 30 00 066    6,48    0   
16 30 00 076    6,48    0
```

Edit: I have built the application without using threading and it is working perfectly, so I can definitely say that the threading is the issue.